# ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'

Tags: oracle, privileges, tablespace

I'm getting this error:

> ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'

I have a default tablespace and I'm able to create tables, however, they do not show at the objects tab in Toad.
I cannot insert anything into tables I create.

Comment: I altered *my* user to no effect. I then altered the *owner* user and was able to add rows.

Comment: @Steve11235 If you think about it, that's the only logical way. The object belongs to the owner, therefore the data 'belongs' to the owner, and therefore the quota of the owner is taken into account (otherwise, Oracle would need to track ownership for every single row in the database - highly impractical and mostly useless).

Comment: This worked for me : GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO <user>;

Answer (score 265, accepted):

You cannot insert data because you have a quota of 0 on the tablespace. To fix this, run

```
ALTER USER <user> quota unlimited on <tablespace name>;
```

or

```
ALTER USER <user> quota 100M on <tablespace name>;
```

as a DBA user (depending on how much space you need / want to grant).

Comment: and how can I know (select?) current quota for a given <user> ??

Comment: @downtheroad Follow-up questions should be posted as separate questions on SO - just go ahead and post it as a new question.

Comment: Saved my day.  Thanks!! Not sure how suddenly the quota became 0

Comment: For my situation, it's schema that need to quota. `alter user <newschemaname> quota unlimited on <tablespacename>`