# ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS' even when tables moved to different tablespaece

Tags: oracle, ddl

I created some tables using **DBO_USER** which had default tablespace as **USERS**. I moved these tables to another tablespace which is **DBO_TS**. I have another user **APP_USER** which tries to insert into these tables created by **DBO_USER** and **APP_USER** has unlimited grants and quotas on DBO_TS tablespace. **APP_USER** gets the error message `ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'.` I can't alter the user as mentioned in

> [ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671008/ora-01950-no-privileges-on-tablespace-users).

I want to know the following:

1. Why error still refers back to USERS tablespace?
2. How can I enable APP_USER to insert into tables created by **DB_USER** 
   without altering the user and default tablespace of the user?

Thanks.

Comment: Does APP_USER do the INSERT directly or via a stored procedure? If the latter, who owns the stored procedure?

Comment: It inserts Directly

Comment: Was APP_USER able to insert prior to the move?

Comment: No which is the reason why I moved the tables to DBO_TS

Comment: Are there any indexes/LOBS on the table that are still in the USERS tablespace?

Comment: @TenG No indexes/LOBS used in the table

Comment: Then you need to post some more details about the table and the user privs here, e.g. dba_ts_quota for APP_USER, dba_tables. I presume that APP_USER has logged out and back in agian to the database since the grant was issued.

Comment: There must be some object still in the USERS tablespace. That's about all anyone can say from what you've told us. A working demo would really help.

Comment: No objects were in Users tablespace as i moved all of them to DBO_TS. I had to change the default tablespace and drop and recreate the objects to make it work. I will check if i can create it out of office.